# Canvas not displaying black PNG or correctly sized

Tags: go, canvas

I have some Go code that generates a black png:

```
    sv = &Server{
        clients: make([]*websocket.Conn, 0),
        canvas:  image.NewNRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height)),
    }

    for x := 0; x < 1024; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < 1024; y++ {
            sv.setPixel(x, y, color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255})
        }
    }
```

And they get converted to bytes and sent to a client like so (confirmed test.png is just a black image):

```
func getCanvas(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := png.Encode(buffer, sv.canvas); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    f, _ := os.Create("./test.png")
    png.Encode(f, sv.canvas)
    b := buffer.Bytes()
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(b)))
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store")
    w.Write(b)
}
```

On the web:

```
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket");
        socket.onopen = async () => {
          const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

          fetch("http://localhost:8080/canvas")
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(data => {
                data.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
                  var arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer);
                  var imageData = ctx.createImageData(1024, 1024);
                  imageData.data.set(arr);
                  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
                })
            });
        };
```

However I have two problems, the first is that the no matter what I try, the image is appearing white (or not rendering at all) in Chrome and secondly, the image doesn't take up the full height it should, it only takes up (1024x150px). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?